# ERROR Class 'CRM_Search_Upgrader' not found since upgrading to 5.45.1 Joomla

Tags: joomla, upgrade, error, search, system

When I try to navigate to "system status" nothing shows up now after upgrading to 5.45.1. I get a blank screen.

When I select "administrator" then select "extensions" I receive the error Class 'CRM_Search_Upgrader' not found and I'm asked to go back to control panel.

When I select Civicrm from the Joomla "components" menu I sometimes off and on get the same error message.

I have no idea how to fix this. Please if you answer, walk me through in baby steps if you know how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That file is part of search kit. What version are you upgrading from?

Comment: I started having issues when I upgraded from 5.44.0 to 5.45.0. I ALWAYS upgrade as the new ones are released. Is there anyway to get that single file and upload it to the file manager in cpanel? Where would I find that file?

Comment: It's [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.45/ext/search_kit/CRM/Search/Upgrader.php), under ext/search_kit/CRM/Search, just it's strange you'd only be missing one file.

Comment: also doesn't the blank screen at system status suggest an angular issue? so there may be more to it than just one missing file

Comment: Thank you both for responding, but I'm not missing the "Upgrader.php" file. I have it in my file manager under the same directory ext/search_kit/CRM/Search I have no idea what to look for next. I have a blank system status screen and I cannot access the "extensions"

Comment: I'm also noticing I have several images broken from my directory now on the front end as well. Some are broken and some aren't? Any suggestion as why that would happen after an upgrade?

Comment: Today, 15Jan2022, I upgraded from CiviCrm 5.36 to 5.45.0 on my staging server which is on Wordpress(5.8.3). I get a Error Thrown ...Class 'CRM_Search_Upgrader' not found when I access the extensions option thru the administration menu. Caches have been cleared, CiviCrm menu rebuilt and rebuilt database triggers through the Civicrm Admin Utilities. I did get the message that the upgrade was successful. Has anyone come across the same issue on Wordpress and be able to assist with a solution?

Comment: Do you have access to the mysql database? Can you do `select full_name,is_active from civicrm_extension;` and update the original question with the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked best for me based off comments and suggestions posted. I'm unfamiliar with MySQL, so I went into my file manager through my hosting and deleted the "Afform" folder found at administrator > components > com_civicrm > civicrm > ext

After I deleted the folder and refreshed the civicrm home page my "system status" and "extensions" were no longer blank and throwing errors that Afform files were missing. I then was able to install the "Search Kit" in the extensions as recommended. I then reinstalled the Afform folders from the most recent downloads. I'm not sure if this route helps others, but thought I'd try to explain.

If anyone wants to reply and educate me on how to work the above suggestions, I would be grateful for the tutorial. I'm able to access phpmyadmin. From there I have access to all the database tables, and I have SQL tab at the top. I was just unsure what to do next. Thanks to all who helped answer my question!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this sporadically and have had to run extension upgrades for Search Kit.

If you go to the system status screen `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/status`  You should see if any extension updates are needed.

You can force the extension upgrades by going to `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fextensions%2Fupgrade&reset=1` or running `cv ext:upgrade-db` if you have cv and ssh access.

Comment: Yes, I too know that updating extensions is the way to go, but after the 5.44.0 upgrade I can no longer see my system status and have a blank screen. I'm not sure how to force the upgrade. I will read more about this. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Can you check the answer from the other post: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41068/error-class-crm-search-upgrader-not-found-since-upgrading-civicrm-to-5-45-1-on. You might have afform-admin installed. If you have access to the mysql database you can try `update civicrm_extension set is_active = 0 where full_name='org.civicrm.afform_admin';` to disable that extension so at least you can get to screens.