# ERROR Class 'CRM_Search_Upgrader' not found since upgrading CiviCRM to 5.45.1 on Wordpress 5.8.3

Tags: wordpress, extension, upgrade, error, accessibility

I upgraded from CiviCrm 5.38 to 5.45.0 on my staging server which is on Wordpress(5.8.3). I get a Error Thrown ...Class 'CRM_Search_Upgrader' not found when I access:

1. CiviCRM from the Wordpress Admin panel for the first time and when I refresh the
   page CiviCRM comes up.
2. Administration>>System status - nothing comes up apart from the wait icon.  (https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/status)
3. The extensions option thru the administration menu. Administration>>>System Settings>>Extensions (https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fextensions&reset=1)

For the upgrade I followed the notes on https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/

Extensions were also brought back as per the notes above. The extensions are:-

1. ca.civicrm.logviewer
2. mosaicotweaks
3. purgelogs-1.1.0
4. uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.booking
5. uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico
6. webtracking-1.3

I don't think that uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.booking is working or has been updated as we were testing this some time ago but abandoned it as there was no support.

Caches have been cleared, CiviCrm menu rebuilt and rebuilt database triggers through the CiviCRM Admin Utilities.

I did get the message that the upgrade was successful during the upgrade process through CiviCRM Admin Utilities.It shows that I am running 5.45.0 on the bottom of https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM

1. Has anyone come across the same issue on Wordpress and be able to assist please with a solution?
2. Do I revert back to CiviCRM 5.36 and wait for the next version CiviCRM 5.46 on my staging server?

Thanking the team in advance.

Comment: Hi, This seems like the same question as https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41044/error-class-crm-search-upgrader-not-found-since-upgrading-to-5-45-1-joomla, but when you say `Extensions were also brought back as per the notes above`, do you mean including the `ext` dir in the civicrm core tree, i.e. the ext folder at the same level as `ang`, `CRM`, `Civi`, etc... Just want to clarify because those core ones should not be restored, just 3rd party ones that usually live in a different folder.

Comment: Thanks Demerit....yes you are correct. I started this question as I believed https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41044/error-class-crm-search-upgrader-not-found-since-upgrading-to-5-45-1-joomla was around Joomla.....it was the 3rd part ext folder that was restored which is in ..../wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext#

Comment: Ok cool. Do you mind updating your question to list which extensions you have installed since I'm trying to figure out if it's some extension that is maybe causing this, since it's not affecting every site.

Comment: Sure...
1. ca.civicrm.logviewer
2. mosaicotweaks
3. purgelogs-1.1.0
4. uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.booking
5. uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico
6. webtracking-1.3

I don't think that uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.booking is working or has been updated as we were testing this some time ago but abandoned it as there was no support.

Comment: The error is definitely related to the SearchKit extension. Has that extension ever been installed on your site (if so then perhaps it's still installed but disabled)?

Comment: Thanks Coleman, How can I check if SearchKit has been installed previously?. As I cant get to the extensions screen (Administer>>System Settings) I cant check if I had it previously on my staging server. On my production server SearchKit shows (CiviCRMv5.38) as a listing but not enabled and can be installed. What are my options for my staging server pls?

Comment: If you have access to the mysql database do `select full_name,is_active from civicrm_extension;`

Comment: Thank you Demerit.... Running this command in phpMyAdmin... select full_name,is_active from civicrm_extension;
 full_name is_active ...
sequentialcreditnotes 1 
ca.civicrm.logviewer 1 
org.civicrm.flexmailer 1 
uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico 1 
eventcart 1 
financialacls 1 
greenwich 1 
contributioncancelactions 1 
recaptcha 1 mosaicotweaks 1 
org.civicrm.afform 1 
org.civicrm.afform-html 1 
org.civicrm.afform_admin 1 
purgelogs 1 
authx 1 
ckeditor4 1 
legacycustomsearches 1 

Should SerchKit come up in this output above?

Comment: This format may be clearer....
 full_name<t>is_active<c>sequentialcreditnotes<t>1<c>ca.civicrm.logviewer<t>1<c>org.civicrm.flexmailer<t>1<c>uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico<t>1<c>eventcart<t>1<c>financialacls<t>1<c>greenwich<t>1<c>contributioncancelactions<t>1<c>recaptcha<t>1<c>mosaicotweaks<t>1<c>org.civicrm.afform<t>1<c>org.civicrm.afform-html<t>1<c>org.civicrm.afform_admin<t>1<c>purgelogs<t>1<c>authx<t>1<c>ckeditor4<t>1<c>legacycustomsearches<t>1<c>

t=tab; c=carriage return;

Should SerchKit come up in this output above?

Answer (score 2):

Aha! Thanks for the list of extensions. You have afform_admin enabled and in 5.45 it started [requiring search_kit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/cb80705c0df2c1e106774ebc74c0452fd1e01f92#diff-7110a32fa979e355db9114edaa4a6622c2cc71b3b3e5a70e5cc01d9532af12cbR26). So it must be looking for it after upgrade.

If you've already upgraded and have access to the mysql database, you can do `update civicrm_extension set is_active = 0 where full_name='org.civicrm.afform_admin';` to disable afform-admin temporarily so you can get to the screens.

If you haven't upgraded yet, this needs to be fixed in core but in the meantime before upgrading you can either disable afform-admin, or install search kit.

Comment: Oh !!....I didn't get any errors during the upgrade though...can you pls suggest what I can do to rectify, thanking you in advance.

Comment: It needs to be fixed in core but basically enable search kit before upgrading and it should be ok then.

Comment: You can try disabling afform-admin from the database so you can get to admin screens: `update civicrm_extension set is_active = 0 where full_name='org.civicrm.afform_admin';`

Comment: Thanks Demerit......it has fixed the issue...Here are my steps....
1.  Set is_active = 0 where full_name='org.civicrm.afform_admin' as per your suggestions above.
2. Cleared CiviCrm cache
3. Went to extensions page and noticed Searchkit was NOT installed but shown on page.
4. Message appeared "extension upgrade pending"
5. ran "Extension Upgrades" noticed that ...org.civicrm.afform_admin was updated in process.
6. cleared Civicrm caches
7. Installed Searchkit on extensions page.

Do I need to enable Form Builder extension?
What is the yellow "flask" icon next to the version number?

Comment: it means it's a pre-version release and not a stable release. this is now since version 5.4X or so I think