# Can't upgrade Mosaico Extension from 2.8XXXX to 2.9 without Afform but no Afform Ext. Available in Joomla

Tags: extension, upgrade, error, mosaico, install

Unable to upgrade Mosaico Extension. I keep getting an error that I need to upgrade Afform from Civicrm.org. (See picture.) I can't find Afform within the extension browser within civicrm, and either way it is already in my file manager and showing to be installed.

I'm attaching the error message that happens when trying to download and install the extension within Civicrm.

[image: screenshot error]

Comment: i have seen some comments previously about issues if Afform (or was it SearchKit) was enabled when it was a non-core extension, but now it is a core extension and perhaps that be an issue to investigate. eg this one but it relates to searchkit https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41068/error-class-crm-search-upgrader-not-found-since-upgrading-civicrm-to-5-45-1-on/41084#41084

Comment: Yes that sounds possible. Or maybe it's just a label vs name thing - if you are looking for "afform" in the UI extension browser you won't find it because it's called Form Core there. I don't know what version you're on but that disconnect was improved in version 5.44 via https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/21852

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I had to upgrade "Form" core component. I kept looking for Afform. Silly me! Thanks folks!

Comment: If your problem is solved, please write up the solution as an answer.  It's easier for others to read an answer than track through comments.

Comment: My apologies Aidan. I've added the answer, which was given by Demerit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Demerit mentioned, I was looking for the name "Afform" and it is now called "Form Core." The error kept throwing me off asking for the extension "afform." I upgraded the extension Form Core and now everything is working well. Thank you for your help.