# Can't update extension: "You will not be able to install/upgrade Edit Line Item Extension until you have installed the org.civicrm.afform extension"

Tags: upgrade, extension, formbuilder, line-items

My Edit Line Item extension stopped working.  It looks like it needs an update, but update fails with the error "You will not be able to install/upgrade Edit Line Item Extension until you have installed the org.civicrm.afform extension".

On the face of it, it seems I have exactly [this same problem](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41358/cant-upgrade-mosaico-extension-from-2-8xxxx-to-2-9-without-afform-but-no-afform) ([Can't upgrade Mosaico Extension from 2.8XXXX to 2.9 without Afform but no Afform Ext. Available in Joomla](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41358/cant-upgrade-mosaico-extension-from-2-8xxxx-to-2-9-without-afform-but-no-afform))

But I do have Form Core installed and up to date (I think? says it's a prerelease version).

Details:
Joomla
CiviCRM 5.66.1
Edit Line Extension v2.6 (wants upgrade to 2.7)
Form Core 5.66.1

Based on other research, it seems Afform/Form Core was an external extensions that became part of core? So maybe this is an out of date dependency problem?  Anyway, how do I fix it? Do I simply need to update Civi to the latest?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afform is shipped with core and is now automatically enabled.  I'd upgrade Civi then try again.

Comment: Thanks Aidan, will do so today and see how it goes.

Comment: It took a while but eventually I did update Civi to 5.70.0, and was able to install the extension.  (The extension itself isn't working properly, but that's another issue....)